# Open xml sdk versus interops for excel for client side automation

Tags: excel, openxml

I would like to automate an excel report client side and I was trying to decide which technology to use, this will be visual studio 2010 and C#. Fairly straight forward report, dump values from sql to excel.

I know of OpenXml (server side) and of the interops (Client side), I would like to use Openxml to the automation client side but I was wondering if this is an accepted practice. Meanning automating excel with open on client side.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

My take will be **Open XML sdk**.

**PIA or Interops** have lot administrative rights requirements like DCOM permissions etc. and hence the deployment and configuration steps are relatively complicated. Good thing about PIA is it is easier to code, slightly faster than open XML and feature rich. For example using PIA it is very easy to convert office document in other formats.

**Open XML sdk** doesn't requires any configuration or seperate installation. Only its libraries are required to be copied. It doesn't need explicit rights as such apart from I/O (can operate smoothely in hardened systems). However, its features are limited. Open xml is very handy for report generation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open XML is only suitable to read and write data from the excel file. if this is your functionality you can easily use Open XMl as it is highly optimized.. else if you want to generate reports, pivot tables... you should go with interop